# MySQL Workbench - "+" is not valid at this position for this server version

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I am working on learning how to create triggers in SQL using MySQL workbench and MySQL server. The trigger is supposed to update a customer's balance in the CUSTOMER table when a new invoice is entered into the INVOICE table. I have the following code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_updatecustbalance
AFTER INSERT ON INVOICE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET CUST_BALANCE = CUST_BALANCE + :NEW.INVOICE_AMOUNT
    WHERE CUST_NUM = :NEW.CUST_NUM
END;
```

As far as I can tell everything for this trigger is set properly, but I am getting an error on the "+" in `SET CUST_BALANCE = CUST_BALANCE + :NEW.INVOICE_AMOUNT`. I haven't been able to find anything online that says why I am getting this specific error.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: I would have expected you to get an error because of the `:`s in front of `NEW`.

Comment: @Nick I was following a tutorial that I found online that had the colon in front of NEW. When I take out the colons, I then get an error on `END` that says "Expected ';' but found END instead."

Comment: Yes, you need a `;` at the end of the `UPDATE` statement i.e. `WHERE CUST_NUM = NEW.CUST_NUM;`. Note that you may then run into an issue with delimiters requiring you to use a `DELIMITER $$` or similar before attempting to define the trigger.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much. I added the delimiter $$ and then added the semi colon at the end of the update statement and it works now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @nick you should post your solution as answer and ekelly should accept that. This is how StackOverflow reputation works.

Comment: @MikeLischke I've voted to close as a typo. I don't see that this question can help anyone else. Better it just get roomba'd